# Using feynmp in overleaf

Tags: overleaf, metapost, feynman, feynmp

I'm trying to create this diagram in overleaf:

[image]

I can create this on texstudio by using the package feynmp, the code is as follows:

```
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,50)
    \fmfcmd{
        path qc[],otimes;
        qc[1] = (0,0) -- (.5,0) & quartercircle & (0,.5) -- (0,0);
        qc[2] = qc[1] rotated 90;
        qc[3] = qc[1] rotated 180;
        qc[4] = qc[1] rotated 270;
        otimes = (qc[1] & qc[2] & qc[3] & qc[4] -- cycle) rotated 45;
    }
    \fmfwizard
    \fmfv{d.sh=otimes,d.f=empty}{l}
    \fmfv{d.sh=otimes,d.f=empty}{r}
    \fmfleft{l}
    \fmfright{r}
    \fmf{photon}{l,vl}
    \fmf{fermion,right=1,label=$k$}{vl,vr}
    \fmf{fermion,right=1,label=$k-q$}{vr,vl}
    \fmf{photon}{vr,r}
    \fmflabel{$j^\mu~$}{l}
    \fmflabel{$~j^\nu$}{r}
    
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Unfortunately on overleaf, it appears to only allow me to use feynmf, an outdated version of the package. Does anyone know how to either get feynmp to work with overleaf, or how to create this diagram with feynmf? I tried compiling and running metapost on my laptop then uploading all the files to overleaf, but this didn't work.

Comment: You should ask Overleaf support for help.

Comment: OT from your question, but `(0,0) -- (.5,0) & quartercircle & (0,.5) -- (0,0);` can be (much better) expressed as `origin -- quartercircle -- cycle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me on Overleaf with `feynmp` and pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,50)
...
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ho. What Is please the rule of declaregraphicrule? Why do you have put this?

Comment: `mps` is the cut-down form of `eps` that MP will produce unless you put `prologues := 3;` at the top.  And the line tells the graphics driver about it.   Not necessary if you use `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: Amazing so if you just put the declargraphicsrule at the top it fixes everything! Thanks :)